# Why HMS Awareness headset connecting barrier status change from connected to disconnected after 5 Seconds?

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

When I am using HMS Headset Awareness connecting barrier will disconnecting headset after 5 seconds. So it make an issue while playing music. How can solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In connecting and disconnecting barrier status will change to FALSE after 5 seconds. You can use keeping barrier to sove your issue.
Use the given link for the reference
https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMS-References/awareness-barrier-headsetbarrier